# CSV imports; all values is one row

Tags: php, csv

I'm having a problem using a CSV file uploaded via a PHP form. Here is the code:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The only problem is, when I'm interrogating the variable `$data` it appears the contents of the CSV file is written to one row, rather than multiple rows. As a result, I get an array of 228 column values.

Why is this? Is my PHP script not detecting a new line correctly? If so, is there an option to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely problem is the line endings in your source data. Could you make a test CSV file with several columns and rows to confirm or eliminate the data you're testing with?

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

Comment: Thanks for this - both the question and the answers, was about to start punching myself in the head in frustration

Answer (score 13):

set the [auto_detect_line_endings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) ini setting to true:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```